# How do I compare the view_sql for two views in Snowflake using an SQL query?

Tags: view, snowflake

I've got two views that are both in Snowflake but within two different databases. I want to confirm that the view_sql for the two views are identical. I am not familiar with python. Is there a way that I can compare the view_SQL for the two views using an SQL query?

Comment: Can you share what queries you've tried that didn't work? Anything in Snowflake docs you found the provide a command to get the view definition?

Comment: I now realize I can use the Notepad++ "Compare" plugin to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

The Notepad++ "Compare" plugin, which I needed to add, definitely worked great for comparing two view_sql's to make sure they match. It shows them side by side on the screen and highlights what is different between the two.